# Registration key cracking tool for an old school game

Tags: reverse-engineering

Good day everyone.

I have a very old offline PC game that needs a registration code to activate its full version.
Unfortunately I am not able to purchase the full game anymore, as it is no longer supported by the developer company, and even the game company is discontinued. Hence I have no choice but to either crack it or to search for the registration code elsewhere.

Hence, to crack it, I am thinking to have a tool that will keep on trying to get the registration code (maybe by brute force attack?) or some tools that will reverse engineering and get me back to the source code from the game executable.

So may I have some recommendations to such a tool?

Thanks!

Comment: You might get some help at https://retrocomputing.meta.stackexchange.com/ It would probably also help if you told us which game; as it stands, you are asking us to give a tool to crack any and every licensing scheme.

Comment: Sorry about that, the game is called Outbreak 1.9 from Jaibo Software. Alien Outbreak 1.0 is a brother version of Outbreak 1.9, both behaves the same, only the 1.0 has more levels.

Answer (score 2):

If the game is genuinely abandonware, you may be able to find the answer by searching at [My Abandonware](https://www.myabandonware.com/).

That site has loads of old out-of-copyright games.

Comment: Thanks for sharing, yes, the game is an abandonware. Tried to search in the website but no luck :(